# How to calculate altitude and inclination of a roof in order to not affect sun going to the garden

Tags: roof, gardening

My house is located in [Buenos Aires, Argentina](https://www.google.com.ar/maps/place/Buenos+Aires,+Argentina/@-34.6156624,-58.5035097,29878m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x95bcca3b4ef90cbd:0xa0b3812e88e88e87!8m2!3d-34.6036844!4d-58.3815591)

It is facing SW. The front has 8,66 meters.

At 3.30 PM March 21, the sun seems to be at 45º of my property.

I want to revive garden where the SUV (car) currently is, and for that I need the sun, so I will be placing the roof covering the SUV (and the SUV also) in the left side of the property. The garden's current roof will be removed.

What I want to know is: **At what altitude, and at what inclination it would be most beneficial to my garden.**

I'm planning to either leave the roof left side (where it touches my neighbor's property) open or adding windows to close it but let the sunlight pass. The roof will be made of better materials, like this:

[image]

I don't want my pine tree to receive a lot more less light and die

House photos

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*I will be placing the SUV roof in the left side of the property*"  Maybe move ALL  of the SUV. Sport Utility Vehicle

Comment: @AlaskaMan Edited for more clarity, sorry, I have some mistakes in English.

Comment: It does not look  like that area gets much sun. Perhaps set up a test roof with a tarp at the time in question to see how shadows are cast on the area.

Comment: @AlaskaMan starting from 11AM to 6PM (in summer) the area gets all the sunlight, starting from the left side first, at 10AM more or less, (The sun rises behind the house). Then it is affected by the trees shadows, but at some point in the evening it gets a little bit more of sunlight. Having the car and the roof killed the sunlight and so the soil became pretty bad and dry.

Comment: There are many "solar angle calculators" on the web, most (not all) of which work worldwide. One chosen at random suggests that as of today, your actual solar elevation angle at noon would be about 30 degrees, not 45.- with a range from 54 in late December to just under 8 in late June. Overestimating the angle without tools is perfectly normal (and has been studied in psychology as perhaps related to the "huge moon at the horizon" perceptive illusion.)

Comment: I'll consider a mono-slope roof, if flat roof is not desirable.

Comment: @ecnerwal I actually went to a solar calculator and angle was 45.3deg at 4pm